# What does the following Regex expression do?

Tags: regex

I would like to understand what the following code is doing.  This logic is part of a routine to strip out html from the body of an email message.

```
mBBSREgEx.IgnoreCase = True
mBBSREgEx.Global = True
mBBSREgEx.Pattern = "<[^>]*>"
sResult = mBBSREgEx.Replace(sResult, "")
```

Thank you,
Jim

Ok, if I wanted to change the routine to strip out tags constructed like [b]Hello[/b] instead of the existing one that strils out "<" and ">" tags, how would I change the pattern?

Would this work?

```
mBBSREgEx.Pattern = "\[[^\]]*\]"
```

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It replaces all tags with empty strings.

It looks for an opening `<`, then takes as many characters as possible that are not `>`, then it finds a closing `>`.  Finally, it replaces all of that (everything from `<` to `>`) with an empty string, effectively stripping out HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern would strip out tags constructed like [b]Hello[/b] instead of the existing one that strips out "<" and ">" tags:

```
mBBSREgEx.Pattern = r"\[[^\]]*\]"
```